Is it possible to do a compressed airdrop of a fungible mint for which uncompressed accounts already exist?
What happens if you mint an SPL token, then use a wallet app to manually airdrop it to a few different accounts, and then do a separate compressed airdrop in which some but not all of the accounts overlap those from the manual (uncompressed) airdrop? Is this even possible? What happens to the overlapping accounts? Do they end up compressed or uncompressed? Is there any way to do this in the CLI?
